# Why am I not receiving income every 20 minutes?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

My automatic income has been spotty, at best.  Having logged several hours of playtime, I've received income exactly twice.  I've specifically tried the following, which seem to have no effect:

- Renovating banks
- Not renovating any banks
- Completing missions
- Returning to Animus Island / completing Desmond's memories
- Doing absolutely nothing for 20 minutes
- Visiting banks without money waiting for me
- Taking over Templar-controlled areas
- Inducing Templars to attack Dens

I have the Steam version of the game and it is up to date as of 12/11.

Are there others experiencing this problem?  Are there any known workarounds?

Comment: I wonder if cut scenes suspend the clock?

Comment: Would be my guess. I never got the update during a cutscene.

Comment: I can't verify the cutscene thing, but as I've sat idle on a rooftop for over 20 minutes, I don't think it's the only problem.

Comment: I've observed this on the Xbox 360 version, too. It definitely doesn't update every 20 minutes of real time.

Comment: @Fredy I've gotten other updates during cutscenes, though - or rather I've heard the "your assassin had a successful away mission" music during the cutscene, and then gotten the text notification as soon as the cutscene ended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, this [seems to be treated by Ubisoft like it was an intended feature](http://ubisoft.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15905/p/88,2366/session/L3RpbWUvMTMyMzkxNTEzOS9zaWQvdndUeG9DTGs=) in many situations.  This leaves some of the situations described in the question unexplained, but according to Ubi's solution center:

> There are a number of things that factor into the bank income timer.
>   The most important thing to remember is that the timer/counter is
>   specific to the Constantinople map. This means that **the timer will
>   reset at certain points during gameplay** (ex: when playing Den Defense,
>   Altair missions, Cappadocia, etc). Also, **the timer will reset if a
>   mission is aborted.**

One more reason to never participate in a Den Defense mission.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't explain why you didn't get it when you just sat there for 20 minutes.

Comment: No, but it does give me a list of things to avoid.  I'm definitely getting money more often now.

Comment: Sounds like a smart strategy might be to wait to start certain types of missions and memories until right after you've had a deposit in the bank - since it's going to restart anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This happens after a certain Desmond memory sequence, but I can't tell you which one right now. The solution is to complete the next Desmond memory sequence and the money starts rolling in again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a bug with the game, try contacting support to see if there is a known issue or to at least bug report it.

Answer (score -2):

My guess would be that your game is not running 60 FPS (or whatever how much FPS ACR has) making the game rolling slower, so it takes longer to pass the 30 minutes.

EDIT: I just remembered. There's 3 times you are supposed to receive cash in the day. Middle of the day, Evening and Dawn.

If you pass all day and dont receive anything, that's gonna be wierd.

Comment: GTX 570, and although I haven't found a way to easily view framerate, I don't think this is the problem.  It never drops to perceptible lag.

Comment: FPS isn't necessarily tied to tracking the passage of time.

Comment: if it's supposed to be 3 times per day/night cycle, we can definitely file this one under bug.  I can confirm going from day, to night, to day without payment.  Now I just need to find the beat-up-shopkeepers-for-your-protection-money quest.

Answer (score -2):

actually, you are supposed to receive revenue once per day. According to the Piggyback game guide, 20 minutes is supposed to equal one day in Constantinople and we are to receive income at each day. If you are telling the truth that you just sat there and timed it for OVER 20 minutes and did not receive any income, then I would have to think that there is some kind of bug.