# How can I check how long I need to wait for the next bank deposit?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I never know how long I have to wait until the next bank deposit. I know it's meant to be every 20 minutes and that there are events that annoyingly [reset the timer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41238/why-am-i-not-receiving-income-every-20-minutes) without telling you, so I was wondering if there's a way to check how much longer I need to wait for the next deposit (assuming it won't be interrupted).

I'd like something more specific than 'dawn, midday, and dusk' because those are just as hard to time as 'every 20 minutes'. Is there a timer anywhere I can have a look at? I've not found anything so far but I've only just started playing and was hoping that after two games they'd include something as simple and useful as this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  There's no timer visible in the game.

When I was in need of money, I tended to just leave the game running and park Ezio in a haystack or rose bush near a bank.  If you leave and eat dinner (for example), when you get back, you should have enough cash to continue.

Comment: d'oh :( I was afraid this was the case...